# How to exclude certain directories/files from counsel-git-grep search?

Tags: git, grep, counsel

Would it be possible to exclude certain directories/files from [`counsel-git-grep`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) search, such as `.gitignore`?

Here I don't want to see matches in `.gitignore` file:
[image: How to exclude ceraa]

I have tried adding `':(exclude).gitignore'` following line but it gives `error code 128` message.

`(setq counsel-git-grep-cmd-default "git --no-pager grep -F -n --no-color -I -e \"%s\"")`

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084612/2402577

Comment: What you have tried looks correct to me, since it works correctly on the command line. Also, you can see that counsel 'formats it correctly' by printing the `funcall` in `counsel-git-grep-function`. So I suggest that you open an issue for it (you might add a link to your post here). Also, maybe remind them that the `':(exclude).gitignore'` should be placed after the search pattern.

Comment: @dalanicolai I opened the issue, please see: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/2903#issuecomment-897525272

Comment: Great! So it seems tricky to implement in counsel (although it is probably easy if you know exactly how Ivy/Counsel works). But there are still multiple alternatives. I would suggest that you open a request at [consult](https://github.com/minad/consult) also. As @minad developed the package himself (AFAIK), it would probably be easy for him to implement this. Further, I have found that probably `helm-git-grep` should already support it, but unfortunately without docs and I could not easily get it to work. But really, consult looks very promising, and I think he will fix it for you quickly.

Comment: @dalanicolai please see: https://github.com/minad/consult/issues/395#issuecomment-897901286
I think `(setq counsel-git-grep-cmd-default "git --no-pager grep -F -n --no-color -I -e \"%s\" -- :!.gitignore")` should work right?

Comment: Yes, and it looks like it does (here). And great that you can also add it [at the prompt](https://github.com/minad/consult/issues/395#issuecomment-897901286).